# Highest theorems in the arithmetical / analytical hierarchy in terms of formula complexity

Tags: logic, soft-question, computability

I am posing this question based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/331285/998803) which asserts that the Riemann Hypothesis is a $\Pi_1^0$ statement while $\mathsf{P}$-vs-$\mathsf{NP}$ is a $\Pi^0_2$ statement ("for every code for a machine of such and such kind there is a code for a machine of such other kind such that ..."). I found it quite surprising that even some of the most complex and deep open questions in mathematics are expressible with formulas of such low complexity. I suppose that formula complexity has nothing to with the question of "how hard is it to prove this statement".

This leads me to my questions:

Are there any known *useful* mathematical theorems or statements that are only expressible as [hyperarithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperarithmetical_theory) or [analytic statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_hierarchy), i.e. that are known to strictly lie above $\Delta^1_0$ on the arithmetic or analytic hierachy?

In other words, what is the highest complexity theorem that exists? (If that even is a sensible question to ask.)

Any mathematical or philosophical answers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Neither RH nor the P=NP are *theorems*.

Comment: It depends on the language you are using, but a lot of theorems are in the $\Pi^1_2$ form (Bolzano-Weierstrass, just to name one). A universal quantification on topologies is $\Pi^2_?$  (the cofinite topology is the smallest $T_1$ topology on an infinite set). Of course you can go higher up, but maybe the *useful* part becomes debatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what counts as "useful" to you, but one example is the following sentence $\varphi$: "There is a well-founded model of ZFC."

$\varphi$ is presumably true, although of course this can't be proven in ZFC because of Gödel's incompleteness theorem. (It *can* be proven, for example, in the theory ZFC + "there exists a strongly inaccessible cardinal," although that's actually much stronger than $\varphi.)$

$\varphi$ is $\Sigma^1_2,$ as you can see by writing out what it means, coding countable structures as real numbers.

But $\varphi$ is not $\Pi^1_1.$ This is because $\Pi^1_1$ sentences are downward absolute: any true $\Pi^1_1$ sentence holds in every transitive model of ZF.  But $\varphi$ is not true in the minimal transitive model of ZFC, even though $\varphi$ is actually true.  (Again, the existence of that model is presumably true but requires a little bit more than ZFC to prove.)